# After installing Bootstrap by Manage NuGet Packages, bootstrap files does not show for referencing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-2.0, manage-nuget-packages

I installed `Bootstrap 4.x` by `Manage NuGet Packages`, but `bootstrap` files does not show for referencing.
I work by `Visual Studio 2017`.

What is it wrong?! How can I fix it?[image]

Answer (score -1):

The Bower package manager is dead for many reasons, but for now you can use package.json instead of bower.json.

If you don't have it, generate it with `npm init` and then install your package like this:

```
npm install --save jquery
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Please use formatting tools within post form to make your post more readable.

Comment: What does Bower have to do with NuGet?

Answer (score -1):

Nuget packages download **Javascript** files to **~/Scripts**
and download the Bootstrap **CSS** files to **~/Content**.
Unfortunately, NuGet doesn't appear to allow you to change the default position of where it puts the files, so you just have to live with it, and carry on.